# BigQuery CAST whole string column to date after LEFT

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, casting

The data came in datetime format but was upload as a string to **BigQuery**.I want to extract only the date part but not the time part. I try to use a subquery using code:

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT(SleepDay,9) AS DATE)
```

but I kept getting: Invalid datetime string **"4/12/2016"** as an error. Please help me fix it thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

try use BIGQuery `parse_date()` function.

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', LEFT(SleepDay,9))
```

Comment: @CIbyL, i have changed the format to %m/%d/%Y, please try again

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using the `LEFT(date_str, 9)` function, since you don't want to parse `12/31/2022` as `12/31/202`. Instead, parse the `date_string` and use the `PARSE_DATE()` function with proper format strings.

```
WITH
dataset AS (
    SELECT "4/12/2016T12:34:56" as SleepDay
    UNION ALL SELECT "4/15/2016T12:34:56" as SleepDay
),
some_how_parse_the_date_string AS (
    SELECT SPLIT(SleepDay, 'T')[OFFSET(0)] as SleepDay_date_string
    FROM dataset
)
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%m/%d/%Y', SleepDay_date_string) as SleepDay_date
FROM some_how_parse_the_date_string
;
```